# while loop never completes

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

The objective of my program is to:

> Write an application to pre-sell a limited number of private concert tickets. Each buyer can buy as many as 6 tickets. No more than 75 tickets can be sold. Implement a program that prompts the user for the desired number of tickets and then displays the number of remaining tickets.  Use a while loop in your implementation. Repeat until all tickets have been sold, and then display the total number of buyers.

I seem to be having a problem with my loop closing, because even when the loop variable gets to its condition limit it still prompts for the number of tickets. Any idea why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TicketCounterHorn {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    int ticketsToBuy;
    int totalTickets =75;
    int buyers = 0;
    int ticketMax = 6;

    while (totalTickets >= 0) {
        System.out.print("How many tickets would you like to purchase: ");
        ticketsToBuy = in.nextInt();

        if (ticketsToBuy <= ticketMax && ticketsToBuy > 0) {

            if (ticketsToBuy < totalTickets) {
                totalTickets = totalTickets - ticketsToBuy;
                buyers++;
                System.out.println(ticketsToBuy);
                System.out.println(buyers);
                System.out.println(totalTickets);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("the total number of buyers is: " + buyers);
  }
}
```

Comment: `while (totalTickets >= 0) { ... }` are you sure that you want to try selling tickets even if you don't have any (when `totalTickets == 0`)?

Comment: yea i changed that but still having the same issue

Comment: Think about what happens if there's one ticket left and the last time around the loop, a buyer tries to buy the last ticket. Because it is not true that `ticketsToBuy < totalTickets` (it's equal), you can never buy the last ticket.

Comment: I guess I don't see this as a bad question as some others do. The intent is quite clear, as is the problem. Could it be more explicitly stated in the question? Sure, but the problem is the loop never terminates, the desired behavior is that the loop should terminate when the last ticket is bought, and that seems clear enough to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the condition

```
if (ticketsToBuy < totalTickets)
```

should also be

```
if (ticketsToBuy <= totalTickets) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the loop condition should be changed to this:

```
while (totalTickets > 0)
```

Otherwise you keep selling even though there is nothing more to sell...

**UPDATE**

As *David Conrad* mentioned in his comment, there is one more issue:

> There is a second problem. The test `if (ticketsToBuy < totalTickets)`
>   must be changed to `if (ticketsToBuy <= totalTickets)`, otherwise you
>   can't buy the last ticket

Thanks, David, for bringing this up!

Comment: thanks i tried that but even then it doesnt display the number of buyers ever it just keeps asking for how many tickets

Comment: why did this answer get down-voted? It is a valid suggestion.

Comment: There is a second problem. The test `if (ticketsToBuy < totalTickets)` must be changed to `if (ticketsToBuy <= totalTickets)`, otherwise you can't buy the last ticket.

Comment: AWESOME! That was it thank you so much!

Comment: @Sva.Mu please update your answer; you were on the right track so I don't want to preempt you by posting a second answer.

Comment: @TobiasGassmann I suspect that it is because of many people believes that answering bad questions is encouraging more of them so they downvote such answers (even if they are helpful).

Comment: @DavidConrad thank you for highlighting this second issue, I didn't notice it upon first reading...

Comment: Thank all of you guys! I just signed up prior to posting my question and I'd have to say this is the nicest and most helpful forum community I've been on!